# I want my android app to resume from the same page where i left reading

Tags: java, android

I have created an e-book app and keeping my pdf in the asset folder.  I am having a problem in resuming my app to start from the same page where I closed it.

```java
.enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(0)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load();
```

Comment: If the activity gets paused or stopped you have to save the current page. And on the next start you set `.defaultPage(lastpage)` instead of `.defaultPage(0)`. Thats what I would assume...

Comment: it gives me an error when i set .defaultPage(lastpage) instead of .defaultPage(0)

Comment: Can you post your code...  Where did you declare, set and save the variable `lastPage`?

Comment: .enableSwipe(true
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false) comments, colors or forms)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(0)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load();

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow and dont know about the formatting .. Sorry !!!

Comment: you can save the last page in sharedpreferences and than load the page you saved everytime the app is opened , in case you haven't saved a thing go to page 0 . Everytime you swipe the page you can update the last page in the sharedprefs

Comment: No problem you could also update the code in your question. See [here how to highlight code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108171/how-do-i-get-code-to-show-up-with-color-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: how can i highlight the codes in 'comments' ?

Comment: @StavroXhardha should put this comment as an answer, and this is the correct one.